# Javascript pseudo-classes, jQuery event handlers and 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I've got a big Javascript project that I'm trying to refactor into pseudo-classes:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/7T42w/

```
var MyNameSpace = {}

MyNameSpace.MyClass = function() {
    this.doSomething = function () {
        return "hello";
    }

    this.doSomething2 = function() {
        var x = this.doSomething() + " world";
        alert(x);
    }

    this.doSomething2(); //Works fine

    $("#mydiv").click ( this.doSomething2 ); //Doesn't work
}

var class = new MyNameSpace.MyClass();
```

The reason the click event causes an error is that `this` refers to the `#mydiv` element.

How am I supposed to design the above so that I can access the element that was clicked but can also call `doSomething()`?

Comment: @Javier JavaScript does not have classes. So it's a pseudo class.

Comment: OO, classes and other things are design concepts, not language features

Comment: Sure they're language features, some languages support different types of inheritence etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cache the context reference and wrap the call in a closure:

```
var MyNameSpace = {}

MyNameSpace.MyClass = function() {
    var context = this;

    context.doSomething = function () {
        return "hello";
    }

    context.doSomething2 = function() {
        var x = context.doSomething() + " world";
        alert(x);
    }

    // You can do this:
    context.doSomething2();

    // Or this:
    $("#mydiv").click(function(e) {
        context.doSomething2();
    });
}
```

Comment: So obvious now :) Just for the record there's no need to wrap the call in a function, if you pass `context.doSomething2` (without brackets) it does the same thing

Comment: I agree, but I like to keep my click event arguments separate from my instance method arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.doSomething2 = $.proxy(function() {
    var x = this.doSomething() + " world";
    alert(x);
}, this);
```

$.proxy binds the `this` scope to the context variable inside said function.

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to `this` in the outer scope:

```
MyNameSpace.MyClass = function() {

    var that = this;

    this.doSomething = function () {
        return "hello";
    }

    this.doSomething2 = function() {
        var x = that.doSomething() + " world";
        alert(x);
    }

    this.doSomething2(); //Works fine

    $("#mydiv").click ( this.doSomething2 ); //Doesn't work
}
```

The function assigned to `doSomething2` is said to "close over" the variables in its lexical scope and so has access to their values even once `MyClass` has returned. This allows us to access the `doSomething` method through the reference to the instance we assigned to `that`.

Comment: Yeah, this would work. The only thing I would recommend is that since you are already caching the context, why not use it everywhere instead of one place. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @Eli personally I don't like using the cached context everywhere. I prefer to only use `that` where I can't use `this`. Better yet bind the method to `this`.